# PHP: POST paired check box/text field in form

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form that is a list of check boxes. Next to each check box is a text field that goes with the check box. Below is an image of what I am talking about
[image]

The text in red is the `name` attribute. My question is based off of whatever the user check marks, how do I match the paired text field without doing a bunch of if statements?

I know how to just post the check boxes and just post the text fields..separately. I guess I am stuck at how to pair the results. This is what I am using to `$_POST` the check boxes

```
if (isset($_POST['family_medical_history']))
{
    $_SESSION['patient_form']['family_medical_history'] = array();
    foreach ($_POST['family_medical_history'] as $key => $value)
    {
        $_SESSION['patient_form']['family_medical_history'][$key] = $_POST['family_medical_history'][$key];
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['patient_form']['family_medical_history'] = "none";
}
```

Example HTML form

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="family_medical_history[]" value="Crossed Eyes" /> Crossed Eyes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="rel_crossed_eyes">
</div>
```

Comment: Post the HTML for the form.

Comment: @larsAnders posted it

Comment: Your foreach is rather pointless. `$_SESSION[...]['history'] = array_values($_POST['family_medical_history'])` is all you need.

Comment: @MarcB ok, thanks for pointing that out. I still need to know how to pair the values. If someone checks `Crossed Eyes` I'd like to `$_POST` the `rel_crossed_eyes` text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair them by naming the inputs similarly for each checkbox/relationship pair to produce a two-member array for each item.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="rel_crossed_eyes[]" value="Crossed Eyes" /> Crossed Eyes</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="rel_crossed_eyes[]">
</div>
```

In the PHP, they will become pairs with the 0 element equal to the value of the checkbox input, and the 1 element equal to the text input. You can create an array of conditions and loop through each of the named inputs. You'll have to change your if statement to something else, for example the submit button:

```
$conditions = array("rel_blindness" => "Blindness", "rel_cataracts" => "Cataracts", "rel_crossed_eyes" => "Crossed Eyes", "rel_glaucoma" => "Glaucoma");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach ($conditions as $key => $value){
        if ($_POST[$key][0] == $value){//if the checkbox is checked
            $_SESSION['patient_form']['family_medical_history'][$key] = $_POST[$key][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, i'm going to give this a try. I'll report back in a few minutes. I didn't realize you can use the `[]` on text inputs. I always thought they were specifically for check boxes

Comment: I *believe* you can use the bracket notation on any HTML input. Correct me if I'm wrong, SO.